# What is a good website for finding Windows 7 themes?

Tags: windows-7, windows, themes, desktop-customization

If I search for `Windows 7 Themes` with either [Google](http://www.google.com/search?q=windows+7+themes&sourceid=ie7&rls=com.microsoft:en-us:IE-SearchBox&ie=&oe=) or [Bing](http://www.bing.com/search?q=windows+7+themes&src=IE-SearchBox&FORM=IE8SRC), I seem to get a lot of spammy websites as results.

Of course there's the [personalization gallery](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/Windows/downloads/personalize) at Microsoft's website, but I'm hoping to find a good website or two showcasing Windows 7 themes outside of Microsoft.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have been unable to find a good site dedicated to Windows 7 themes, here are some sites suggested on a recent [Lifehacker poll for the **Five Best Wallpaper Sites**](http://lifehacker.com/5434865/five-best-wallpaper-sites):

- [InterfaceLIFT.com](http://interfacelift.com/wallpaper_beta/downloads/date/any/)
- [Vladstudio.com](http://www.vladstudio.com/wallpapers/)
- [Social Wallpapering](http://www.socwall.com/)
- [Deviant Art](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/wallpaper/)

There was another site that Lifehacker recommended, but I found some of the ads on that site to be NSFW so I didn't include it in this list.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried DeviantArt?

I don't beleive there's a dedicated section yet, but the Windows Vista section has been full of Win7 themes since the first betas.

Comment: where exactly are you referring to on the DeviantArt site? I see lots of wallpapers, but I can't find anything with packages of actual "Themes." Am I missing something?

Comment: [This](http://browse.deviantart.com/customization/#catpath=customization/skins/vistautil/visstyles&order=5) section contains many a Win7 theme.

Answer (score 1):

I agree. DeviantArt is one of the best sources I have seen. I have been using it for a few years and have got some really cool themes, especially backgrounds for my PC.

They even have some skins for Rainmaker.

Just some excellent art work there by some really talented people.